# Char arrays filled with 0xCC after allocation

Tags: c++, malloc

[image: -52 = 0xCC]

So after allocating char array in debugging windows I can see my array is filled with 0xCC. What does it mean? (-52 = 0xCC)

Comment: Show the relevant code or didn't happen.

Comment: You will find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new

Comment: Protip - right click and turn on hex display so you can see the hex displays directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninitialized built-in types have an in-determined value, trying to read it is undefined behavior.

The actual values you can see depend on the compiler: You might for example see garbage, zeroes or (what seems to be the case in your example) some special value indicating *"data uninitialized"*.

Answer (score 1):

It's there as a sentinel value so that you know that the memory is uninitialized.

See the [/GZ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699247%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) compiler switch.